# OpenIdConnect verify jwt from OpenId Provider

Tags: jwt, openid-connect, openid-provider

We have a web application Vuejs(front) and a api Nodejs(back).

We delegate authentication to a third party OpenIdProvider.

Users login in the front and get and access token.

This access token contains:

- **nbf** : the time before which the JWT MUST NOT be accepted for processing.
- **iat**: the time at which the JWT was issued.
- **exp**: time expiration of token

In my case when i log in at 11am i have:

- nbf: 11:00 am
- iat: 11:00 am
- exp: 11:30 am

In each request from VueJS to NodeAPI, the access token is passed and verified by the back.

I verify jwt token like this:

```
jwt.verify(token, publicKey, { algorithms: ['RS256'], audience: process.env.OP_CLIENT });
```

The publicKey is read from the OpenIdProvider jwks_uri and the audience is my provider client id.

The problem is that the time on my nodejs server is late, is it : **9:00**

So when i use verify i get this error message:

> NotBeforeError: jwt not active
> at /var/www/app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:143:21
> at getSecret (/var/www/app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:90:14)
> at Object.module.exports [as verify] (/var/www/app/node_modules/jsonwebtoken/verify.js:94:10)
> at async authUser (/var/www/app/src/helpers/openid.js:87:19) {   date: 2021-07-27T09:00:51.000Z }

I read that I could ignore the notBefore option but the problem remains the same on the validity period of the token ?
because with a time difference between the issuing time of the provider and the time on my server it distorts the verification.

what do you recommend ? is this the correct way to verify my token from a provider?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Gary !
Finally i set
**ENV TZ="Europe/Paris"** in my docker file and my backend is now at the good timezone.

I also added the deactivation of the notBefore check to avoid problems if it has a few minutes of lag

```
jwt.verify(token, publicKey, { ignoreNotBefore:true, algorithms: ['RS256'], audience: process.env.OP_CLIENT });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks pretty standard - similar to [this code of mine](https://github.com/gary-archer/oauth.apisample.nodejs/blob/master/src/plumbing/oauth/tokenvalidation/jwtValidator.ts).

The times used should be UTC times, so the preferred resolution is to ensure that the UTC time on the server is correct - eg by running a simple OS command such as `date -u` in bash.

Note also that there is an option called [clockTimestamp](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) that can be passed into the Auth0 library.

This will not help if the server clock is badly wrong though. If an IT administrator runs the server, it is their job to ensure that the system clock is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Our server is running inside a docker container in a swarm cluster.

So i think, i have to set correctly the good UTC timezone in my deploy stage